# Problems overriding less operator for unique items of a set

Tags: c++, set

I have the following class with three member variables.

```
Edge::Edge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, float initialCost)
{
    if (v1.getId() < v2.getId()) {
        _v1 = v1;
        _v2 = v2;
    } else {
        _v1 = v2;
        _v2 = v1;
    }
    _cost = initialCost;
}
```

And the < operator defined as such

```
bool operator<(const Edge &lhs, const Edge &rhs) {
    return (lhs._v1.getId() != rhs._v1.getId() || lhs._v2.getId() != rhs._v2.getId()) && lhs._cost < rhs._cost;
}
```

Here's how the vertex class is laid out

```
Vertex::Vertex(int id)
{
   // _position = position;
    _id = id;
}

int Vertex::getId() {
    return _id;
}
```

I'm implementing it the following way in a set.

```
        set<Edge> test = set<Edge>();

        Vertex v0 = new Vertex(0);
        Vertex v1 = Vertex(1);
        Vertex v2 = Vertex(2);
        Vertex v3 = Vertex(3);
        Vertex v4 = Vertex(4);
        Vertex v5 = Vertex(5);

        Edge e1(v0, v1, 0.2);
        Edge e2(v1, v2, 0.4);
        Edge e3(v2, v3, 0.7);
        Edge e4(v3, v4, 0.6);
        Edge e5(v4, v3, 0.6);
        Edge e6(v4, v5, 0.3);
        Edge e7(v4, v1, 0.4);

        test.insert(e1);
        test.insert(e2);
        test.insert(e3);
        test.insert(e4);
        test.insert(e5);
        test.insert(e6);
        test.insert(e7);
        Edge e(v1, v2, 0.0);
        cout << "ERASING" << endl;
        test.erase(e);
        cout << "DONE" << endl;
```

I would expect that the erase statement at the bottom would only erase e2 from the set. The behavior I want is to be able to erase elements in the set based on their vertices, without having to specify their cost value.

What's actually happening is that every edge except e3 and e4 is being removed from the set. If I don't call erase, I get my expected behavior (only those edges with the same vertices are considered duplicates). Why is this happening?

Comment: please post an [mcve]. Emphasis on minimal

Comment: `std::swap` can help here

Comment: @John My bad, I had fixed that already. That wasn't the true problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operator for unique containers must meet all requirements for strict weak ordering. To oversimplify the main requirement, somewhat, strict weak ordering means that: 1) if `a<b` is true, and 2) `b<c` is true, then 3) `a<c` must also be true.

Your `<` operator violates this rule. It is not difficult to come up with three `Edge`s that will violate this rule, for example:

```
Edge    v1->getId()    v2->getId()    cost
 A:        1              2            10
 B:        3              4            11
 C:        1              2            12
```

Your `<` operator will return true for `A<B` and true for `B<C`, but false for `A<C`.

Answer (score -1):

`std::set` requires your `operator<` to implement a [strict weak ordering](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585396/what-is-meaning-of-strict-weak-ordering-in-laymans-term). Your `operator<` is broken, because for two `Edges` `a` and `b`, both `a < b` and `b > a` can be true, even if `a != b`.

```
bool operator<(const Edge &lhs, const Edge &rhs) {
    return (lhs._v1->getId() != rhs._v1->getId() || lhs._v2->getId() != rhs._v2->getId()) && lhs._cost < rhs._cost;
}
```

This returns `true` for any two `Edges` whose `_v1` have different id.